# Use SD card for inputStream (images) android instead of internal memory

Tags: java, android, bitmap, inputstream

I'm trying to grab (with the method below) an image from the internet and do some canvas work with. but sometimes i'm having outOfMemory exception. So i'm wondering if is there a way to load the inputStream directly in the memory card instead of the internal memory.

```
private Bitmap LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
{   

   try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap().copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        return bitmap;
        }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc="+e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

the logcat says that the exception is due to that line :

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
```

Thx in advance!

Comment: it might help if you elaborate, what exactly exception you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took this code from Fedor Vlasov's lazylist demo:
[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012).

First you need to create a function to copy your input stream to file output stream:

```
public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
{
    final int buffer_size=1024;
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
        for(;;)
        {
          int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
          if(count==-1)
              break;
          os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

Then get a cache folder:

```
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyCacheDir");
    else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
```

Then load your bitmap:

```
 private Drawable getBitmap(String url) 
{
    String filename=URLEncoder.encode(url);
    File f= new File(cacheDir, filename);

    try {                        
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();            

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));            
        return new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}
```